# Equivalent MySQL code for the following SQL Server code?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I performed a self join on the *nashvillehousing* table, to replace NULL values in the *PropertyAddress* column, after finding that each unique *PropertyAddress* value has a unique *ParcelID* value.

The online tutorial I'm following uses SQL Server. Unfortunately I am unable to install it in my PC.

I am trying to find an equivalent MySQL Code for the following SQL Server code.

```
UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = ISNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM projectportfolio.nashvillehousing a
JOIN projectportfolio.nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID != b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: THINK about your code. If you filter the rows you select from a based on NULL, then there is no good reason to use ISNULL when setting the value. a.PropertyAddress will always be NULL and you want to overwrite it with whatever b.PropertyAddress contains. You SHOULD however ignore rows where b.PropertyAddress is also NULL since that logically changes nothing. Rule to learn - do NOT perform pointless updates.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM projectportfolio.nashvillehousing a
JOIN projectportfolio.nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this would be:

```
UPDATE projectportfolio.nashvillehousing nh JOIN
       projectportfolio.nashvillehousing nh1
       ON nh1.ParcelID = nh.ParcelID AND
          nh1.UniqueID <> nh.UniqueID
    SET nh.PropertyAddress = nh1.PropertyAddress
    WHERE nh.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

Note the additional changes to the query:

- The use of meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.
- Getting rid of `ISNULL()` -- or `COALESCE()`.  This is unneeded because of the `WHERE` clause.
- Qualifying the name of the column being updated.